# CRM 4 importing rdl error Root element is missing

Tags: xml, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-4, rdl

When Importing my rdl file from a SSRS project into the CRM 4 reports area, I get this error.

**Root element is missing**

How can I handle that?

Comment: Which version of reporting services are you using?

Comment: SSRS 2005, but that is not important, see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@niktrs, thanks but the problem was different.

Actually just figured out that the file that I downloaded on the server from Outlook Web Access Email was empty. checked with notepad.

I copied the contents from the local file into that empty file and saved as the same file with UTF-8 format.

It imports fine without trouble, obviously!